# How can I combine two gradient tapes in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

How can I combine the two following gradient tape, into one:

```
x = tf.Variable(x, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    m, v = DGP.predict(x)
    dm_dx = t.gradient(m, x)
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    m, v = DGP.predict(x)
    dv_dx = t.gradient(v, x)
```

Here's what I prefer but does not work the way I have written it:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    m, v = DGP.predict(x)
    dm_dx, dv_dx = t.gradient([m,v], x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
x = tf.Variable(x, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as t:
    m, v = DGP.predict(x)
    dm_dx = t.gradient(m, x)
    dv_dx = t.gradient(v, x)
```

Comment: A warning comes about persistent being very inefficient but I guess that's still the only way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the need for persistent tape, you could do this:

```
x = tf.Variable(x, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as t1, tf.GradientTape() as t2:
    m, v = DGP.predict(x)
    dm_dx = t1.gradient(m, x)
    dv_dx = t2.gradient(v, x)
```